# Is it possible to merge the book and books tags?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Subject says it all.

Comment: merged books -> book ... book was the more prevalent tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1, Sounds logical to me. I can't really defend the need both singular *and* plural in this instance.  May be worth submitting a [Tag Synonym](https://serverfault.com/tags/synonyms) based on the MSF feedback.

Comment: A good idea: http://serverfault.com/tags/book/synonyms